# Disable automatic white balance and set a fixed value with python

Tags: python, opencv, camera, settings

I'm trying to control the camera parameters of a USB-camera live using Python with Windows 10. Using OpenCV it's fairly easy to control them using the module VideoCapture. However, this is not true for automatic white balance enabling/disabling and white balance setting.

Looking at what I found on the OpenCV documentation I found this:

*CV_CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE Currently unsupported*

If I open a software like ManyCam or AMCap I can easily control it, like you can see in the following picture, but I found no way to do it in Python software live.

[image: camera properties]

Is there any method (also a workaround, such as command line stuff that can be called from Python code) to toggle AWB and set WB value on the fly using code?

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows you can worarkound using `cfg-cam` to set camera settings to specific values

Download the release from https://github.com/SuslikV/cfg-cam

then save the current camera settings by running

```
WebCameraConfig.exe --savedev
```

after that, each time you open the `WebCameraConfig.exe`, it will load those values. You can easily alter those values by altering the values in `cam_sett.cfg`